# Importing an Oracle 7 DMP into Oracle XE 18c

Tags: oracle, oracle-xe, oracle7

I need to be pointed in the right direction, as I am getting nowhere.
I have been handed a project from some years back which has a VB6 front end with an Oracle back end, and for some reason Access in the middle.  The VB6 I am fine with.

What I am trying to achieve is to import an Oracle 7 DMP file into a fresh install of Oracle XE 18c.

What I need is to be pointed towards some documentation with examples, and maybe an area to look at.  I am new to Oracle so really have no clue where to begin.

Where I am currently:

1. I have downloaded and installed a copy of Oracle on my Windows 10 PC (64Bit)
2. Copied the DMP file into the correct directory.
3. Ran the following command, and I get the errors that follow

```
D:\Oracle\ImportDB>impdp dumpfile=BA0211070.DMP

Import: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Wed Mar 27 11:04:58 2019
Version 18.4.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Username: SYSTEM
Password:

Connected to: Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
ORA-39001: invalid argument value

ORA-39000: bad dump file specification

ORA-31619: invalid dump file "D:\Oracle\admin\xe\dpdump\BA0211070.DMP"
```

I have also tried:

```
impdp dumpfile=BA0211070.DMP FULL=Y VERSION=7
impdp dumpfile=BA0211070.DMP FULL=Y
```

I got the same results as above.

I have tried Googling the error messages, but that hasn't really shed much light.  I can't get a fresh DMP file as we don't have an Oracle installation anymore, so unfortunately I have to work with what I have.

Comment: If it's really Oracle 7, you'd need to use the old-school `imp` utility (which is depricated in Oracle 18) rather than `impdp`.  But I'm pretty sure that you're going to be outside of the compatibility window-- the version of `imp` that ships with Oracle 18 probably can't deal with an Oracle 7 dump file.  I'd need to get on Oracle Support and pull up the compatibility matrix but I'd expect that you'd need to do one or two intermediate hops to get all the way from 7 to 18.

Comment: No, I think an oracle 7 DMP will work in 18. But yes, you need to use IMP program on the client or database host, and NOT data pump

Comment: I migrated from Oracle 8.1.7.4 32 bit Solaris 9 to Oracle 11.2.0.3 64 bit Oracle Linux 6 64bit using exp and imp.

Comment: Oracle export from Oracle 7.3 (AIX) to Oracle 11g (Linux) https://puredba.co.uk/oracle-export-from-oracle-7-3-aix-to-oracle-11g-linux/

Comment: Thank you all for the help.  It has pointed me in the right direction.